# Largest of the three numbers python program

Tags: python-3.x

This is Python program to find the larger of the three numbers. But I also I would to run the program again. I used the def again function with if statement. But I am unable to rerun the program

```
def max_num(num_1, num_2, num_3):
    if num_1 >= num_2 and num_1 >= num_3:
        return num_1
    elif num_2 >= num_1 and num_2 >= num_3:
        return num_2
    else:
        return num_3


def again():
    cal = input("Do you want to run the program again, "
                "if yes please select y"
                "else select n ")
    if cal == 'y':
        max_num(a, b, c)
    elif cal == 'n':
        print("See you")
    else:
        print("Please select the right option ")


a = input("enter number 1: ")
b = input("enter number 2: ")
c = input("enter number 3: ")
print("The largest number between {}, {} and {} is:".format(a, b, c))
print(float(max_num(a, b, c)))
max_num(a, b, c)
again()
```

Comment: You're not calling `again` once you call it once. You can use a `while` loop though to keep running until `cal == 'n'`.

Comment: Just use the `max()` function. `max(1,2,3)` gives 3

Answer (score 0):

since you are reading the inputs outside the max_num() function, calling it again won't make it ask for inputs again. I added the queries to the function and i hope it works as you intended.

```
def max_num():
    highest = None
    a = input("enter number 1: ")
    b = input("enter number 2: ")
    c = input("enter number 3: ")
    print("The largest number between {}, {} and {} is:".format(a, b, c))

    if a >= b and a >= c:
        highest = a
    elif b >= a and b >= c:
        highest = b
    else:
        highest = c
    print(float(highest))


def again():
    cal = input("Do you want to run the program again, if yes please select y, else select n")
    if cal == 'y':
        max_num()
    elif cal == 'n':
        print("See you")
    else:
        print("Please select the right option ")



max_num()
again()
```

as suraj-subramanian pointed out in the comments, using the `max` function will rid you of the long if expressions:

```
def max_num():
    highest = None
    a = input("enter number 1: ")
    b = input("enter number 2: ")
    c = input("enter number 3: ")
    print("The largest number between {}, {} and {} is:".format(a, b, c))

    highest = max(a,b,c)
    print(float(highest))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling max_num() inside if condition but not printing anything.

```
if cal == 'y':
     max_num(a, b, c)
```

Chnage it to

```
print(float(max_num(a, b, c)))
```

Whole code base

```
def max_num(num_1, num_2, num_3):
    if num_1 >= num_2 and num_1 >= num_3:
        return num_1
    elif num_2 >= num_1 and num_2 >= num_3:
        return num_2
    else:
        return num_3


def again():
    cal = input("Do you want to run the program again, "
                "if yes please select y"
                "else select n ")
    if cal == 'y':
        print(float(max_num(a, b, c)))
    elif cal == 'n':
        print("See you")
    else:
        print("Please select the right option ")


a = input("enter number 1: ")
b = input("enter number 2: ")
c = input("enter number 3: ")
print("The largest number between {}, {} and {} is:".format(a, b, c))
print(float(max_num(a, b, c)))
again()
```

Or if you want user to enter new value each time when again() function runs. then

```
def max_num(num_1, num_2, num_3):
    if num_1 >= num_2 and num_1 >= num_3:
        return num_1
    elif num_2 >= num_1 and num_2 >= num_3:
        return num_2
    else:
        return num_3


def again():
    a = input("enter number 1: ")
    b = input("enter number 2: ")
    c = input("enter number 3: ")
    print("The largest number between {}, {} and {} is:".format(a, b, c))
    print(float(max_num(a, b, c)))

    cal = input("Do you want to run the program again, "
                "if yes please select y"
                "else select n ")
    if cal == 'y':
        again()
    elif cal == 'n':
        print("See you")
    else:
        print("Please select the right option ")

again()
```